# Use dplyr's if_else function with functional true/false values

Tags: r, dplyr

### Question

How can dplyr's `if_else()` function be used such that its output is a function? With `ifelse()` from `base` this is trivial but with `if_else()` something goes wrong. Is that intended behavior or am I just not able to do that properly?

### Reprex

```r
x <- 2
ifelse(x == 2, min, max)
#> function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("min")
dplyr::if_else(x == 2, min, max)
#> Error in true[rep(NA_integer_, length(condition))]: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You shouldn't even be using `ifelse` for this. `ifelse` and `if_else` are for vectors. Your `ifelse` code will fail with a strange error if `x` has length > 1, try setting `x = 2:3` and running your code. When you're checking a condition that should always have length 1 you should use `if(){}else{}`, and the result can be literally any expression. Save `ifelse` (and `if_else`) for vectors as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ifelse` for this. `ifelse` and `if_else` are for vectors--specifically for when **your input is a vector and your output is a vector of the same length**. You can't make vectors of functions, so `ifelse` is a poor choice for returning a function. Your code will only work in the special case when the input has length 1---which is what the control/flow function `if()` is for.

Your `ifelse` code will fail with a strange error if `x` has length > 1, try setting `x = 2:3` and running your code.

```
> x = 2:3
> ifelse(x == 2, min, max)
Error in rep(yes, length.out = len) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'builtin'
```

`if()`, on the other hand, will still check the first element and return the correct result for the first element while giving you a warning  about the input length:

```
> if(x == 2) min else max
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("min")
Warning message:
In if (x == 2) min else max :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

When you're checking a condition that should always have length 1 you should use `if(){}else{}`, and the result can be literally any expression, it can be assigned, or it can be arbitrary code that is run. Save `ifelse` (and `if_else`) for vectors as intended.

Comment: Why can't I make vectors of functions? Do you refer to vectors as atomic vectors specifically, then I agree. But technically a list is a vector to and `c(min, max)` returns a list of those two functions. For using a vector and multiple functions would you recommend approaches like @TimTeaFan suggests?

Comment: Yes, it's a little inexact, but I usually refer to atomic vectors as *vectors* and lists as *lists*.

Comment: The `ifelse` documentation says that the `test` argument is *"an object which can be coerced to logical mode."* Since `list`s aren't coercible to a logical atomic vector, and `ifelse` returns *"A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as `test`"*, you couldn't use `ifelse` to return a list of functions. There are `purrr` functions, or even ways to use `lapply`, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is always a scalar then using `if` as described in @Gregor Thomas answer is the correct approach.

Another option would be to use `switch`, which makes sense, if you have more than two options and want to minimize the control flow:

```r
x <- 2
min_max <- switch(as.character(x), `2` = min, max)
```

If, however, you are actually dealing with a vector for example in a {dplyr} pipeline, then using `character` vectors instead of functions in combination with `do.call` is one approach.

Here is a short example where we want to use a different function (`min` or  `max`) depending on the `am` group in `mtcars`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  nest_by(am) %>% 
  mutate(min_max = if_else(am == 1, "min", "max"),
         mpg = summarise(data, x = do.call(min_max, list(mpg)))$x)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Rowwise:  am
#>      am                data min_max   mpg
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     0           [19 × 10] max      24.4
#> 2     1           [13 × 10] min      15
```

Another approach is to wrap each `min`, `max` in `list()`. In this case, we do not need `do.call`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  nest_by(am) %>% 
  mutate(min_max = if_else(am == 1, list(min), list(max)),
         mpg = summarise(data, x = min_max(mpg))$x)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Rowwise:  am
#>      am                data min_max   mpg
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <list>  <dbl>
#> 1     0           [19 × 10] <fn>     24.4
#> 2     1           [13 × 10] <fn>     15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `if_else` is feasible or preferable over base `ifelse` in this case. `dplyr::if_else` uses subsetting in its source (use `if_else` without brackets). To recreate the error, try running `min[]`.

We can try to "repair" the function by altering the code that intends to coerce the output to be of the same class as the `true` and `false` values by subsetting it:

```
out <- true[rep(NA_integer_, length(condition))]
# to pseudocode
out <- "whatever the typeof(true) value is"
```

and use `:::` to get the appropriate internal functions that `dplyr` uses.

```
if_else <- function (condition, true, false, missing = NULL) {
  if (!is.logical(condition)) {
    bad_args("condition", "must be a logical vector, not {friendly_type_of(condition)}.")
  }
  out <- NA_integer_
  out <- dplyr:::replace_with(out, condition, true, dplyr:::fmt_args(~true),
                      glue::glue("length of {fmt_args(~condition)}"))
  out <- dplyr:::replace_with(out, !condition, false, dplyr:::fmt_args(~false),
                      glue::glue("length of {fmt_args(~condition)}"))
  out <- dplyr:::replace_with(out, is.na(condition), missing, dplyr:::fmt_args(~missing),
                      glue::glue("length of {fmt_args(~condition)}"))
  out
}
x = 5
if_else(x == 2, min, max)

Error: `true` must be an integer vector, not a primitive function.
```

This error is the result of a type check in internal function `check_type` within `replace_with`, that looks like this:

```
if (identical(typeof(x), typeof(template))) {return()}
```

Here `template` is `out`, defined in `if_else`.

- typeof Na_Integer_ is *"integer"*
- typeof min is *"builtin"*

A solution to outputting a function `min` or `max` from `dplyr::if_else` would then be how to coerce `out` to be of type *"builtin"*, and to redefine`dplyr` internal functions, for example `replace_with` that uses another another subsetting operation that fails for the same reason as `min[]`.

That is, changing `out` to a builtin like `min` still throws an error:

```
if_else <- function(...){
  ...
  out <- # if out <- min
  ...
}
Error in x[i] <- val : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

So, this is intended behavior, but perhaps `object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable` is not the intended error message to be displayed.